# Paginate relations per-model with BookshelfJS

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I need a way to query for a collection of parent models, limiting it to 8 children per parent within the `withRelated` object.  However, any limits placed within `withRelated` apply to all of the children as a whole, so if the first parent had 8+ children, only the first parent's children are returned according to the limit.  Is there a way to have these limits apply on a per-parent basis, where the limit of 8 applies to the amount of children to get per parent, rather than to the entire children collection.

Example:

```
Parent
    .query()
    .fetchAll({ child: qb => qb.limit(8) })
    .then(done)
    .catch(error);
```

OR

```
const Parent = bookshelf.model('Parent', {
...
    children: function() { return this.belongsToMany('Child', 'parent_id').query(qb => qb.limit(8)) },
...
});
```

Both options seem to limit the entire child collection of all parents as a whole instead of each individual parent's children.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.. explain bit more

Comment: Note that Bookshelf is an ORM, not really a query builder, as its underlying Knex is. Were you able to build such a query in plain SQL? I think it is possible, but not trivial. Once having a valid query you may use [Bookshelf's query builder](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-query) or, more probably, [Knex's one](http://knexjs.org/#Builder).